# Run Sonic Heroes on modern graphics

Tags: technical-issues, sonic-heroes

Decided to revisit a classic from my childhood - Sonic Heroes 2003-2004. It runs decently on my onboard graphics Intel HD 5500, but there are times where the FPS drops and these occasions are quite often.

I have tried numerous times to force Nvidia graphics but to no avail. I have tried to run the game in win7 or win XP compatibility mode. Even disabled the Intel graphics processor but that only led to the game using Microsoft Default Display Driver or whatever.

I read somewhere that newer Nvidia graphics cards have compatibility issues with games that run Direct X 9.0 or lower, but im not sure how to debug this.

Does anyone have any idea how to get Nvidia GTX 940 M to run instead of the onboard graphics for Sonic Heroes?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the gpu your game uses in the nvidia control panel in the "Manage 3D settings" menu like this:
[image: nvidia control panel settings]
If your game doesn't show up in the dropdown menu, add the `.exe` file with the `Add` button.

Comment: Nah man ive tried this and it doesnt work. That was the first thing I tried...

Comment: How can you tell it is running with the intel gpu instead?

Comment: well the launcher of the game outputs the name of the graphics processor it has detected. Cool for troubleshooting but its read-only, i cant use a dropdown list to chose another GPU

Comment: Many games will only detect the intel gpu, but it's up to the nvidia driver to switch to the nvidia gpu once the game is launched. Try setting your drivers to run the game with the integrated intel gpu and see if it gets worse.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually right about Nvidia having issues with games running DirectX lower than version 9.0, the game will not start from the discrete GPU no matter what.
The fix is simple however, just use [d3d8to9](https://github.com/crosire/d3d8to9/releases) to bump Direct3D 8 to 9.0, then change Nvidia Control Panel or Windows settings for the game accordingly.